# Black scratch screen in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I'm at the beginning stage of developing an AR application through Unity. When I integrate the project into the phone, it works, but the screen shows black cuts.There was no problem when I tested it with another android phone. I don't understand what the problem is. I'm using Unity 2019.4.0f1 and the phone I have is the samsung J7. How can I solve it ? [image]

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this on an Android phone too, and disabling Vulkan did the trick. You can find that in **Player Settings** for Android, under **Other Settings**, *Graphics APIs*. Remove Vulkan from the list. You may have to uncheck **Auto Graphics API** first, if that is on.